# How did Cypher meet with Agent Smith?

Tags: the-matrix

Inspired by [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/252019/106741), how can Cypher secretly meet in the Matrix with Agent Smith?  I mean, unless I'm mistaken, every other trip into the Matrix had an operator sitting back on the ship watching what was going on.  We know the operators have a pretty good view, Cypher can tell red-heads, blondes, and brunettes apart just looking at the code.  Maybe the operators can't hear the conversation, but if I were an operator I'd find it suspicious to see Cypher having dinner with an Agent.  When Neo walks in on Cypher at the computer, he certainly seems startled which leads me to believe this is when he was meeting with Agent Smith; and yet we see him in the Matrix, enjoying matrix steak as though he was plugged in.

Another problem is, how did Cypher get plugged in for the meeting, and unplugged after the meeting?  All these issues make me think the Cypher-meeting-with-Smith scene is a big plothole, but maybe I'm missing something.